# How to calculate a value for all rows in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query, sql-server-2019

I have two tables. One is a linking table to handle a many-to-many relationship between users and construction projects, and the other one is a payment table which includes the users' payments. Now I want to calculate each user's payment to show it along with user's information. 
To do this, I wrote this query.

```
SELECT MemberID,
MembershipDate,
(SELECT SUM(Amount) from Payment where MemberID = 1001) AS Payment
FROM   User_Project_LinkingTable where MemberID = 1001
```

Now, how can I do this for all users to show all of them in a list?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, check [GROUP BY column-expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#group-by-column-expression--n-)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to mix 'Group By' and my query... That's the problem. @Ronaldo

Comment: Please note that I calculate payment amount from another table. They are not in the same table @Ronaldo

Comment: Yes, when working with more than one table you can use [Joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver15). Your query would look something like this: `SELECT upl.MemberID, upl.MembershipDate, SUM(p.Amount) AS Payment
FROM Payment AS p
 INNER JOIN User_Project_LinkingTable AS upl
 ON p.MemberID = upl.MemberID
GROUP BY upl.MemberID, upl.MembershipDate;` But the result of the query won't be precise if the same MemberID has more than one registry on the table User_Project_LinkingTable (which is exactly the purpose of a linkin table).

Comment: I believe you have other tables that joined correctly would produce the desired result from the query above, but if you really need to use only Payment and User_Project_LinkingTable, this other query shall give you the right result: `SELECT DISTINCT UPL.MemberID,
 UPL.MembershipDate,
 PaymentSum.SumAmount
FROM User_Project_LinkingTable AS UPL LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT MemberID, SUM(Amount) AS SumAmount FROM Payment GROUP BY MemberID) AS PaymentSum
 ON UPL.MemberID = PaymentSum.MemberID;`

Comment: Glad I could help. And I hope you understood how to use the GROUP BY and JOIN in order to use the proper tables on the query (like **User** and **Payment** if they both have MemberID). That way you can use a query like the first one, which is easier to read and maintain.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide, I'm sorry. I wasn't notified of your comment. But I see Commander has already corrected my mistake. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query solved my problem.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  UPL.memberid, 
  UPL.membershipdate, 
  PaymentSum.sumamount 
FROM user_project_linkingtable AS UPL 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
            memberid, 
            Sum(amount) AS SumAmount 
            FROM payment 
            GROUP BY memberid) AS PaymentSum 
 ON UPL.memberid = PaymentSum.memberid;
```